# SharePoint templates, any good book, internet sites, guides?

Tags: template, books

because I don't want ask here more stupid questions, I think I need to study SharePoint more. But, can you recommend any good books/internet sites/guides where I can learn more about SharePoint 2013 and Visual Studio solutions.
It seems, that I have found only how I can create webparts, edit master page and so on...

But I want to learn; how I can create new Visual Studio project from scratch, deploy it to SharePoint and create new custom site collection, which have custom page, custom webparts and so on...

How I can create master page or what is right way to do it. 
How I can create my own Web template.
I hope that you understand what i'm looking for...

I have used this guide now:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2013/10/17/creating-a-clean-visual-studio-solution-from-a-sharepoint-2013-site-template.aspx
but I want learn more and I have to many questions.

Comment: Hi user20968 and welcome to SharePoint.StackExchange! I've converted this to a Wiki, since it's primarily opinion based. This means that it is still a very valid question, but it doesn't have a definitive answer. Nice to see you here!

Answer (score 1):

You can take this course [Developing Microsoft SharePoint® Server 2013 Core Solutions Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-core-solutions-jump-start#?fbid=P97PqyKJbML) It covers the basic development for SharePoint 2013.

If you want get advanced training you can register to the upcoming online training: [Developing SharePoint Server Advanced Solutions](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/liveevents/developing-sharepoint-server-advanced-solutions#?fbid=P97PqyKJbML) December 13, 2013 9:00am–5:00pm PST

If you want books, I recommend this tow :

[image]

**[Microsoft SharePoint 2013 App Development](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145371805.do) By Scot Hillier, Ted
   Pattison**

- Publisher: Microsoft Press
- Released: November 2012, Pages: 202

[image]

**[Exam Ref 70-331: Core Solutions of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145376954.do)
   By Troy Lanphier**

- Publisher: Microsoft Press
- Released: June 2013, Pages: 544